# Adding load up procedures after the panorama start up animation has finished

Tags: c#, performance, windows-phone, startup, panorama-control

On my panorama app I have a a couple of start-up procedures under the `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded event`. However this results in a pause of about 0.5 seconds before you get the Panorama slide-in animation on start-up.

My question is, is there another `_Loaded` event (or something similar) which I can place these start-up procedures in, which is after the panorama slide-in animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be propably best if you do your startup-procedures in a different thread.

Comment: I guess you do some computation intensive stuff. Do it non an non-UI thread and it will not interfere with the Panorama

Comment: I'm sorry i'm fairly new to the whole c# thing. How do I create/what is, a non-UI thread?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I used the `BackgroundWorker` instead because I couldn't figure out how to use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` however even though it does eliminate the pause at the beginning, it results in a juttery slide-in animation.

Comment: Ah never mind, it seemed to be laggy on the emulator but works fine on the phone